# how do i luanch npm on linux mint ulyana and fix the ENOENT?

Tags: linux, bash, npm, npm-start

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/blackrose_darkchild/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/blackrose_darkchild/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/blackrose_darkchild/.npm/_logs/2020-08-11T13_39_19_447Z-debug.log
```

cant seem to be able to work around this problem,
tired

```
  394  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash 
  395  sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
  396  sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make
  397  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
  398  node --version
  399  npm --version
  400  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
  401  clear
  402  nvm install node
  403  nvm install --lts
  404  nvm ls
  405  nvm use 14.7.0
  406  sudo apt update
  407  sudo apt install nodejs npm
  408  nvm ls
  409  nvm use 12.18.3
  410  sudo apt install nodejs npm
  411  nodejs --version
  412  nodejs --v
  413  sudo apt install nodejs 
  414  sudo apt install npm
  415  sudo apt install nodejs npm
  416  sudo apt install build-essential
  417  npm -v
  418  npm start
```

but still same error